# MySQL query with 2 SELECTs, UNION and LIMIT - how to count all items?

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't figure out how to count results from my query because I `limit` the output:

```
(SELECT "new" as type, name FROM newUsers WHERE name LIKE '%John%')
UNION
(SELECT "old" as type, name FROM oldUsers WHERE name LIKE '%John%')
ORDER BY 1 ASC LIMIT 1, 10
```

The farthest I got was to do `SELECT COUNT(*) ( my query ) as userCount` but then I don't get all other fields that were outputted by my query.

Comment: What are you after really?  A count of the number of "new John" rows and their details, plus a count of the number of "old John" rows and their details, but only wanting 10 rows in total?  I think you're mixing two different queries a bit too thoroughly; you probably need to run two separate queries - one to obtain two values (the number of new and the number of old "John" entries), and another to obtain up to 10 rows of information about old or new John rows.

Comment: @Jonathan, you're correct in guessing what I want. The reason why I am trying to get a count is to display the # of pages that one would have to go through to display all items (assuming there are, say, 10 items per page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably answer the letter of what you seem to be asking for, but isn't a very sensible way to formulate the query:

```
SELECT c.numusers, n.type, n.name
  FROM (SELECT "new" AS type, name  FROM newUsers WHERE name LIKE '%John%') AS n
  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS numusers FROM newUsers WHERE name LIKE '%John%') AS c
UNION
SELECT c.numusers, o.type, o.name
  FROM (SELECT "old" AS type, name  FROM oldUsers WHERE name LIKE '%John%') AS o
  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS numusers FROM oldUsers WHERE name LIKE '%John%') AS c
ORDER BY 1 ASC LIMIT 1, 10
```

The only oddity here is that there is no join condition (neither an ON nor a USING clause) between the two tables.  You might need to use a CROSS JOIN instead of an (INNER) JOIN; alternatively, you can introduce a column `"new" AS type` to the count query, and join `ON n.type = c.type`.  You might then need to add a GROUP BY clause - in most DBMS you would need it, but MySQL may let you get away without it.

However, I think you would do better with two separate queries - one for the type and name as in your question, and the other as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numusers, "new" AS type
  FROM newUsers
 WHERE name LIKE '%John%'
 GROUP BY type
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numusers, "old" AS type
  FROM oldUsers
 WHERE name LIKE '%John%'
 GROUP BY type;
```

Given that you are using MySQL, you may be able to get away without the GROUP BY clauses in the second query.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I was trying to overcomplicate things and am better off going with two queries. It also seems to be a faster way according this comparative analysis: http://bit.ly/zAP52

Comment: Combining these two queries is an example of a problem diagnosed in [SQL Anti-Patterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) and specifically Chapter 18 'Spaghetti Query'.

Answer (score 2):

```
( select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ...)
union
( select ...) // not using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS here
order by ... limit ...;
```

After getting result from the first query,
you can query again

```
 select found_rows(); // to get all the rows count
```

The info from [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)